# Conjecture: If second derivative of a function is positive everywhere then it has no absolute maximum.

Tags: calculus

I am studying calculus but came across a problem which I believe needs the above theorem. I am at a loss....

Comment: That depends on the domain of the function: for example the answer might be different for the non-negative real numbers, compared with the positive real numbers

Comment: What about $f(x)=x^2$ on $[0,1]$?

Comment: I have assumed Domain=R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**: If the function $f$ is everywhere twice-differentiable, at a local (or absolute) maximum point $x=a$, you must have $f''(a)\le 0$.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you're asking about a function defined (and twice differentiable) on all of $\Bbb R$.

**Hint:** By the second derivative test, any critical point will be a local minimum

Answer (score 3):

Differentiating a function tells you its gradient function, inputting a value into this function gives you the gradient at some point.

Differentiating the gradient function tells you what is happening the gradient, that is: whether it is increasing or decreasing, and at what rate. If the second derivative is positive everywhere, it implies that the gradient *never decreases*, and therefore that the curve never slopes down - which means it has no maximum.